# Canvas javascript event based on a object

Tags: javascript, canvas, drawing, line

I need to do an action onclick of a particular (point) or a rectangle in a canvas.

Example:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    var canvas = $('#myCanvas').get(0);
    if (!canvas.getContext) { return; }
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.fillRect(150,140,8,8);
    ctx.fillRect(200,120,8,8);
    ctx.fillRect(200,160,8,8);

});
```

I need to connect two points with a line and another two points with a curve using javascript .How can i do this?

Comment: One option is to use canvas library like [Fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com). Then you can just work with rectangles as objects (`rect.on('click', function(){ ... })`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to maintain the regions yourselves. There are no objects on a canvas, only pixels and the browser does not know anything about it.

<kbd>**[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/jKMgQ/)**</kbd>

You can do something like this (simplified):

```
// define the regions - common for draw/redraw and check
var rect1 = [150,140,8,8];
var rect2 = [200,120,8,8];
var rect3 = [200,160,8,8];

var regions = [rect1, rect2, rect3];
```

Now on your init you can use the same array to render all the rectangles:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var canvas = $('#myCanvas').get(0);
    if (!canvas.getContext) { return; }
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    //use the array also to render the boxes
    for (var i = 0, r; r = regions[i]; i++) {
        ctx.fillRect(r[0],r[1],r[2],r[3]);
    }
});
```

On the click event you check the array to see if the mouse coordinate (corrected for canvas) is inside any of the rectangles:

```
$('#myCanvas').on('click', function(e){

    var pos = getMousePos(this, e);

    // check if we got a hit
    for (var i = 0, r; r = regions[i]; i++) {
        if (pos.x >= r[0] && pos.x <= (r[0] + r[2]) &&
            pos.y >= r[1] && pos.y <= (r[1] + r[3])) {

            alert('Region ' + i + ' was hit');
        }
    }
});

//get mouse position relative to canvas
function getMousePos(canvas, evt) {
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    return {
      x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
      y: evt.clientY - rect.top
    };
  }
```

Also remember to redraw the canvas if the window is re-sized or for other reason clears the canvas (browser dialogs etc.).

To connect the boxes you need to store the first hit position and when you get a second hit draw a line between them.

<kbd>**[Demo with lines here](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/FdGed/)**</kbd>

Add to the global vars and also make canvas and context available from global (see fiddle for related modifications in onready):

```
var x1 = -1, y1;
var canvas = myCanvas;
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
```

And in the click event:

```
$('#myCanvas').on('click', function(e){
    var pos = getMousePos(this, e);
    for (var i = 0, r; r = regions[i]; i++) {
        if (pos.x >= r[0] && pos.x <= (r[0] + r[2]) &&
            pos.y >= r[1] && pos.y <= (r[1] + r[3])) {

            //first hit? then store the coords
            if (x1 === -1) {
                x1 = pos.x;
                y1 = pos.y;

            } else {
                //draw line from first point to this
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.moveTo(x1, y1);
                ctx.lineTo(pos.x, pos.y);
                ctx.stroke();

                x1 = -1; //reset (or keep if you want continuous lines).
            };
        }
    }
});
```